# Is there a recommended path for storing temporary files in a tmpfs/ramdisk which also does not need to be persisted after boot?

Tags: linux, posix, fhs

I would previously just use `/tmp` however this seems to persist after boot, it also seems to be have the disadvantage about literally writing to the disk as opposed to a ramdisk / tmpfs.

I thought perhaps `/run/` but this seems (at least on my Nixos system) to be owned by the `root` user.

Is there any recommended directory for this use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On any systemd-based system, the location matching your requirements most closely is [your subdirectory of `/run/user`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/file-hierarchy.html#/run/user/), or rather, the directory indicated by `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR`. This is flushed whenever the owning user session stops (typically, when the user logs out).

As far as the FHS goes, it doesn’t specify storage properties apart from durability; the appropriate location according to that *is* [`/tmp`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/hier.7.html).